# Mezzanine 4.0.1 - python manage.py createdb always create sqlite

Tags: django, mezzanine, manage.py

This is happening with Mezzanine 4.0.1 on Ubuntu, in venv. Python 3.4.3

After creating a Mezzanine project, I changed the database connection settings in settings.py as:

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
    "NAME": "mezzaninedb",
    "USER": "mezzanine",
    "PASSWORD": "mezzaninepwd",
    "HOST": "localhost",
    "PORT": "5432",
}
```

}

I have created (in Postgresql) a Mezzanine user with password mezzaninepwd and database mezzaninedb, and I "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mezzaninedb TO mezzanine;"

Than, I run:

```
python manage.py createdb
```

It displays in terminal everything that it should display, asks me to create user, email, password...
After it finished, i "psql" into postgresql and connect to mezzaninedb, but **no tables are created in that (PostgreSQL) database**.
**However, dev.db is created in "local dir**" and when I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I can see mezzanine UI, but mezzanine is using Sqlite.

This happens even if I completely remove this from settings.py

```
#DATABASES = {
#"default": {
#    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
#    "NAME": "mezzaninedb",
#    "USER": "mezzanine",
#    "PASSWORD": "mezzaninepwd",
#    "HOST": "localhost",
#    "PORT": "5432",
#}
#}
```

I even tried to completely "literally remove" this section from settings.py and run

```
python manage.py createdb
```

it created all tables, but in sqlite - dev.db.

**So, It never creates postgresql tables, but always creates sqlite db and tables, even if DATABASES {...} is not present.**

I suspected that this might be DJANGO problem, so I created django project and django app, and some models.
After using the same DATABASE {...}  in settings.py, and run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Tables were created in POSTGRESQL !!!

Just to mention, I tried the same

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

in mezzanine, and it behaved the same as createdb - **did not create anything in PostgreSQL**.

**Is this known mezzanine problem or I am doing something very very wrong ?**

Comment: Try local_settings.py

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Mezzanine documentation is mentioning local_settings.py under Deployment section. A little misleading. Thank you, again, Stephen. This answered my question, but you used "comment" for answering question? WIll you answer it or I can do it, but hate to take credit for something that you did ?

Comment: @DarkoStefanovic I have the same problem, however after I set my configuration in local_settngs.py, createdb fails with "CommandError: Database already created, you probably want the migrate command" -- how did you create the new db?